# Stack Overflow top menu bar not being rendered properly in Chrome

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

[image]

The top menu bar is not being rendered properly for `stackoverflow.com`.
Is someone else facing the same issue? Whats the possible solution?

OS: MacOS 10.9
Browser: Google Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125

Here is the screenshot on the Firefox browser
[image]

Comment: What isn't being rendered properly? I don't see anything wrong in that image. Is the Stack Exchange dropdown not visible?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Also, I don't understand why would someone down-vote this question ? If this is not relevant here then where else ?

Comment: first guess on the downvotes is that you are not clearly explaining the issue.  The fact that @AstroCB had to guess your problem means that your question is not clear.

Comment: Works fine for me, with Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: Any console errors? It could be failing to load the resource.

Comment: Are you seeing any JavaScript or network errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the extension (AdBlock) which was preventing the js to load.

I had enabled [fanboy annoyance filter list](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/fanboy-annoyance.txt) as an option available with the AdBlock extension disabling which helped render the site without any issue.

Thanks to the comments posted that led to finding the cause and solution.

Comment: In particular is it the `/share-sprite-` filter that blocks http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=2d10b452229b