# Old data values in title bar when using mobile Chrome's back button

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, top-bar

I am having slightly a different setup than in this question:

[Stack Overflow top menu bar not being rendered properly in Chrome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266143/stack-overflow-top-menu-bar-not-being-rendered-properly-in-chrome)

but the same issue:

My machine is a Asus tablet with a native Chrome, and my issue is that top menu bar gets on points section and notifications old values, when I navigate back on questions page, where I am browsing tabs of listed questions and then press the browser back button.

I am not aware of any ad-blockers (at least I haven't installed one) and thus the solution to disable one as in the linked question is not an answer in here.

Comment: You mean your "Inbox" and "Achievements" icons retain their notification ("1", "+20") when you click them, then go back a page?

Comment: Yes, and total score gets some yesterday value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflow sends a rendered page to your browser.  That render includes the current notification state.  When you click the menu, JavaScript clears that state.  When you navigate back, the browser re-renders the page *as it initially received it*.  It does not re-execute JavaScript events.  Refresh the page to re-render with the latest state.